# Filter for partner user

Tags: community, filters

I have a lookup on Account, this is a lookup to a Account which related to Contacts who are Community Users. I want to create a filter for Account lookup so that it only show the related to Contacts who are Community Users. Can anybody guide me how to get this solved.

Comment: Where are you talking about applying a filter? In a report, list view, etc?

Comment: i need filter on a lookup field.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is going to be challenging to do unless you've created a RecordType or a special field in Contacts for the Community User to indicate that the Contact has been enabled for the Community. If you haven't, you'll need to collect a set or list of all the contacts for the Account, then run a query on Users (I'd limit it to those with the PortalUser profile) to see which ones are returned who have those contact ID's.

Its not going to be a single look-up process that involves a single query without adding additional fields to contacts.

Comment: Once you have a special field in place you can use a trigger to automatically populate it when a portal user is created.  In any case, this is only possible with custom development.